# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' since SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, cross-domain

I've recently switched over to using secure requests with an SSL Certificate. Since I've switched over I'm getting the following error,

> Failed to load
>   https://example.com:2096/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M33Uhsp:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 521.

I've tried setting the origin of `socket.io` to the domain of our website but that didn't solve anything. I'm unsure if this is related to anything else but when I used an normal `http` request it worked fine. What is missing? (cors?)

Comment: Either make the ports match or use CORS.

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 521* = “Web Server Is Down:
The origin server has refused the connection from Cloudflare.” per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#521 and “This status code is not specified in any RFCs, but is used by CloudFlare's reverse proxies to indicate that the origin webserver refused the connection” per https://getstatuscode.com/521 and longer, detailed explanation from Cloudflare at https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171916-Error-521-Web-server-is-down

Comment: The only reason you’re seeing a CORS error is that most web servers by default won’t add additional headers to 5xx (or 4xx) error responses. So your CORS config gets ignored by the web server when it sends that 521 response.

Comment: @sideshowbarker how can I then solve this, I'm unsure.

Comment: Make the request not serve an error.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not even connecting to my nodejs server anymore, so I have to solve this error somehow, it's not throwing it for no reason, I'm pretty sure I have to set the origin to my domain somewhere.. I just don't know where..

Answer (score 0):

I just create key and cert file and include as following.

```
    var app = require('../app');
    var server = https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/driver_app/key.key', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/driver_app/cert.crt', 'utf8'),
         requestCert: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },app); 
    var ios = require('socket.io')(server);
    require("../socket/socket")(ios);

    // socket.js is 
  module.exports = function(io){

    io.use(require('socketio-wildcard')());

    io.use(require('./middleware'));

    io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
      console.log("connection done")
      socket.on("error", (err)=>{
            console.error("server err", err);
       })
    })

    }
```

where app is my express app and socket/socket.js is my socket.io app. This works fine for me